# python dynamodb, scripts returns empty and does nothing

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, boto3

im trying to do a simple put_item inside a dynamodb table, but when i run the script, it doesnt return anything, and the table is still the same, what im missing?

```
import boto3

dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb')
table = dynamodb.Table("Servicio")
def lambda_data_handler(event, context):
    response = table.put_item(
        Item={
         'ID':"6"
        #'Objeto': { "S": "Testeo" } <--- this one didnt work either
        },
       ReturnValues='UPDATED_NEW'
    )
    return(response)
```

Also tried with this code and didnt work either https://youtu.be/aMQT6qcyS94?t=352

Comment: By default nothing is returned:  If `ReturnValues` is not specified, or if its value is NONE , then **nothing is returned**.

Comment: Do you get any errors somewhere indicating that the item is not inserted?

Comment: No, nothing is returned, not error, nothing

Comment: Specify `ReturnValues` to get a return. Otherwise nothing is return.

Comment: specified, but still nothing is returned, and apart from that, there's no changes in the DB

Comment: Have you checked CW logs? If there is error, it will be in the CloudWatch logs for your lambda

Comment: i feel stupid, i was trying it on a cli and not in lambda, but anyway, runed it in lambda and now it throws this error   "errorMessage": "Handler 'lambda_handler' missing on module 'lambda_function'",
  "errorType": "Runtime.HandlerNotFound"

Comment: So you know why it does not work - your lambda throws an exception. Double check that `lambda_data_handler` is set as your handler in lambda settings.

Comment: Thanks. And if you have new issue. Can make new question.

Comment: found an answer to the problem, i was using old syntax from sdk1, thanks anyway for everything

Comment: Glad it worked out and could help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the boto3 [docs](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/dynamodb.html#DynamoDB.Client.put_item):

> Use ReturnValues if you want to get the item attributes as they
>   appeared  before they were updated with the PutItem request.
>
> NONE - If `ReturnValues` is not specified, or if its value is NONE , 
>   then **nothing is returned**.  (This setting is the **default** for
>   ReturnValues .)

Also based on the comments the problem was the the python script was being executed from CLI, not lambda.